# Getin range while using uencode() function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, quantization

I'm using uencode to quantize matrix this way:

```
quantized = uencode(impact_factor_matrix,5);
```

where impact_fator_matrix is a 512x512 matrix of floating point values basically between 0 and 3
a small fragment of this matrix looks like this:

> 0,0199035905058660     0,0172736449099186  0,0180819705503344
>
> 0,0622572806364690    1,13389341902768    1
>
> 0,0606586901989121    1,27920429813366    1

so using uencode gives me levels that I need but I can't figure what ranges is used by this function to assign values to quantization levels
to be specific for this 3x3 example I get

> 16 16 16
>
> 16 31 31
>
> 16 31 31

I can't find out what ranges are used to assiggn to quantization levels. How is this calculated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using the default value for `v`, which is 1, and therefore all values of `imapct_facotr_matrix` larger than one are saturated at 31. try `uencode( impact_factor_matrix, 5, 3 );`

Comment: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/signal/ref/uencode.html  output y are unsigned integers with magnitudes in the range [0, 2n-1]. Elements of the input u outside of the range [-1,1] are treated as overflows and are saturated. So in your case the range is 0:31 (but everything above 1.0 is saturated

Comment: @seb this is total range but I need to know midranges :P I don't know how to expalin this: 0-0.11 = 1; 0.11 - 0.22 = 2; and so on

Comment: You mean something like: `n=5;[ [0:2^n-1]./2^n; [1:2^n]./2^n; [0:2^n-1];].'`

Comment: I did not actually try, so there might be an offset to use. Anyway I don't think there is a special Matlab function, so unless someone knows one, you might need to compute it yourself, similar to what I wrote (again there might be boundaries issues so better try)